# JQuery Independent Functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, compression

Basically, Im wanting to know if the functions in JQuery are independant so I can split up the file using PHP and use only the functions I need, 1 to increase pagespeed and also save bandwidth, I also thought this would be a really good idea because I can control what functions I have via the backend. Are the Functions Independent Or do they need to stay together, many thanks

Comment: Unless you really know what you are doing I wouldn't do it, doesn't have that much impact. Instead minify and gzip the file and let it be served gzipped, this will give you more impact on page speed and bandwidth. And you are able to update jQuery without deleting half the file every now and then...

Comment: Yes, the person who answered said pretty much same, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some yes, some no, but the results you are trying to achieve are best done with something like [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com)

Furthermore, you could actually slow down the page instead of speed it up.  By using the standard google cdn jquery, almost all visitors to your page will already have jquery cached on their system, and so the load will be [essentially zero](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/). You can't beat that with even a jquery 50% size.

Comment: Thanks, also il upvote the comment and set it as correct answer when stack overflow lets me and also thanks for the link